# Using Nav tabs, first tab is always selected when I choose another tab in React Bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I am having an issue with `Nav` in `react-bootstrap` code as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink, useRouteMatch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import NavbarDefault from '../NavbarDefault/NavbarDefault';
import DashboardSwitch from '../DashboardSwitch/DashboardSwitch';

const Dashboard = () => {
    const { url } = useRouteMatch();

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="bg-light">
                <Container fluid>
                    <NavbarDefault />
                </Container>
            </div>

            <Container fluid>
                <Nav className="mt-4" variant="tabs">
                    <Nav.Item>
                        <Nav.Link 
                            as={NavLink} 
                            to={`${url}`} 
                            eventKey="link-1"
                        >
                            HOME
                        </Nav.Link >
                    </Nav.Item>
                    <Nav.Item>
                        <Nav.Link 
                            as={NavLink} 
                            to={`${url}/bonus`} 
                            eventKey="link-2"
                        >
                            BONUS LIBRARY
                        </Nav.Link >
                    </Nav.Item>
                    <Nav.Item>
                        <Nav.Link 
                            as={NavLink} 
                            to={`${url}/newpage`} 
                            eventKey="link-3"
                        >
                            NEW PAGE
                        </Nav.Link >
                    </Nav.Item>
                    <Nav.Item>
                        <Nav.Link 
                            as={NavLink} 
                            to={`${url}/mypages`} 
                            eventKey="link-4">
                            MY PAGES
                        </Nav.Link >
                    </Nav.Item>
                    <Nav.Item>
                        <Nav.Link 
                            as={NavLink} 
                            to={`${url}/account`} 
                            eventKey="link-5"
                        >
                            MY ACCOUNT
                        </Nav.Link >
                    </Nav.Item>
                </Nav>
            </Container>

            <DashboardSwitch />
        </div>
    );
};

export default Dashboard;

const DashboardSwitch = () => {
    const { path } = useRouteMatch();

    return (
        <Switch>
            <ProtectedRoute exact path={`${path}`} component={Home} />
            <ProtectedRoute exact path={`${path}/home`} component={Home} />
            <ProtectedRoute exact path={`${path}/bonus`} component={Bonuses} />
            <ProtectedRoute exact path={`${path}/newpage`} component={NewPage} />
            <ProtectedRoute exact path={`${path}/mypages`} component={MyPages} />
            <ProtectedRoute exact path={`${path}/account`} component={Account} />
            <Route path="*"><NotFound /></Route>
        </Switch>
    );
}
```

Navigation between pages seems to work, but for the tab UI, the HOME tab is always selected:

[image]

I already removed the `defaultActiveKey` prop but the issue still persists. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because every path matches the `${url}` path.

For instance, if you have a page called `/test` and other called `/test-2`, clicking on the page that goes to `/test-2` would activate the tab that goes to `/test` too, since `/test` is included in the `/test-2`.

Pass the prop `exact` to you `HOME` NavLink and you will not see it selected anymore unless the path is exact `${url}`.

```
<Nav.Link 
  as={NavLink} 
  to={`${url}`} 
  eventKey="link-1"
  exact // add this
>
  HOME
</Nav.Link >
```

Comment: Wow. Fantastic working now thanks. I didn't realize I could use `exact` on `Nav.Link` thought it only worked for `Route`.